# Change button color onclick AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, button, angular-ui

I have two buttons. When I click one they both turn blue. Can anyone explain to me how to make it so that on the only selected is blue and when it is not selected goes back to white? 
Here's my site: http://test.shibagames.com

Also why does the dropdown not work when I click it?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why both buttons turn blue, is because both buttons are associated with the same state variable `$scope.isActive`. You need to keep two different state variables to manage both buttons.

Also the reason why the dropdown doesn't show is because bootstraps javascript won't work in its default form with angular. You need to use something like angular-ui-bootstrap, http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

EDIT (updated):

You could do the buttons as follows:

```
ng-class="{'btn-primary': active == 'upload'}" ng-click="activateButton('upload')"
```

Note that you usually don't need to turn off `btn-default`, as `btn-primary` should override the styles anyway (but that is up to you).

Then have the scope function:

```
$scope.activateButton = function(name) { $scope.active = name; }
```

As for ui-bootstrap not working, you really need to follow the simple instructions on the website front page. Under *installation* it explains that you need to add the ui.bootstrap module dependency:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: Ok two things. I got the selecting to work, but I want it to only select one button at a time. So If I click Upload and it turns blue and then click Download, then upload goes back to white and download turns blue.

Also I added angularui bootstrap but the dropdown still doesn't work. I updated the site so here you go. http://test.shibagames.com

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your changing the btn class to btn-primary when the scope variable `isActive` is true. Therefore by clicking either one the `toggleActive()` is fired setting the `isActive` to true and turning both "blue".

The simple solution is something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isActiveUpload,  'btn-default':!isActiveUpload}" ng-click="isActiveUpload = !isActiveUpload">Upload</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isActiveDownload,   'btn-default':!isActiveDownload}" ng-click="isActiveDownload = !isActiveDownload">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this.

```
<div ng-app="plunker">
    <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="buttons = [ {name : 'Upload', isActive :true},{name : 'Download', isActive : false}]">
        <button type="button" ng-repeat="btn in buttons" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':btn.isActive,  'btn-default':!btn.isActive}" ng-click="toggleActive(btn)">{{btn.name}}</button>
    </div>    
</div>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.toggleActive = function(btn) {    
        btn.isActive = !btn.isActive;
    };
});
```

**Updated source to toggle**

```
<div ng-app="plunker">
    <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isUploadActive}" ng-click="toggleActive1()">Upload</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isDownloadActive}" ng-click="toggleActive2()">Download</button>        
    </div>    
</div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isUploadActive = false;
    $scope.isDownloadActive = false;

    $scope.toggleActive1 = function() {
        if($scope.isDownloadActive) {
            $scope.isDownloadActive = !$scope.isDownloadActive;
        }
        $scope.isUploadActive = !$scope.isUploadActive;
    };

    $scope.toggleActive2 = function() {    
        if($scope.isUploadActive) {
            $scope.isUploadActive = !$scope.isUploadActive;
        }
        $scope.isDownloadActive = !$scope.isDownloadActive;
    };

});
```

Comment: I tried that and updated the site again, but the buttons aren't deselecting when I click the other button. They both stay blue unless clicked twice. Which is undesired. One button can only be blue at one time.

Comment: Thank you that worked Mahesh. But the dropdown isn't working still. Do you know whats wrong with that as well. http://test.shibagames.com